# Changing state in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to add an element to an array in the `state` and change another array element's property. Say we have the following `state` structure:

```
{
  menuItems: [{
    href: '/',
    active: true
  }]
}
```

After dispatching the `ADD_MENU_ITEM` action I want to end up with this `state`:

```
{
  menuItems: [{
    href: '/new',
    active: true
  }, {
    href: '/',
    active: false,
  }]
}
```

I have tried managing this in Redux [reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) in several fashions:

```
function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_MENU_ITEM: {
      let menuItems = state.menuItems;
      let newMenuItem = action.newMenuItem; 

      // First try
      menuItems[0].active = false;
      menuItems.unshift(newMenuItem);
      state = Object.assign({}, state, { menuItems: menuItems });

      // Second try 
      menuItems[0].active = false;
      menuItems.unshift(newMenuItem);
      state = Object.assign({}, state, {menuItems: Object.assign([], menuItems)});

      // Third try 
      menuItems[0].active = false;
      state = (Object.assign({}, state, {
        menuItems: [
          Object.assign({}, newMenuItem), 
          ...menuItems
        ]
      }));

      // Fourth try
      menuItems[0].active = false;
      state = update(state, {
        menuItems: {$unshift: new Array(newMenuItem)}
      });

      console.log(state);
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

In the fourth try, I am using React's [Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) but it never works. I logged the state to the console before returning the state and it logs correctly, but when logging inside the components which get re-`rendered`, the menuItems array does not add the first item, although the `active` member is set to `false`.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The state in the reducer should be immutable and for this reason should not be modified. It is also recommended to flatten your object whenever possible.

In your scenario your initial state could be an array as such:

```
[{
    href: '/',
    active: true
  }]
```

In your reducer, try returning a brand new array as follows:

```
function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_MENU_ITEM: {
      return [
        action.newMenuItem,
        ...state.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, { active: false }))
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

More information about reducers can be found here: [Redux Reducers Documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html)

Helpful excerpt from the documentation:

> It’s very important that the reducer stays pure. Things you should never do inside a reducer:
>
> - Mutate its arguments;
> - Perform side effects like API calls and routing transitions;
> - Calling non-pure functions, e.g. Date.now() or Math.random().

**MORE INFO ADDED**

In your reducer, and for all four tries, you are modifying the existing state before returning it.

This results in `react-redux`, when checking if your state has changed, not to see any changes as both the previous and next states are pointing to the same object.

Here are the lines I am referring to:

*First Try:*

```
  // This line modifies the existing state.
  state = Object.assign({}, state, { menuItems: menuItems });
```

*Second Try:*

```
  // This line modifies the existing state.
  state = Object.assign({}, state, {menuItems: Object.assign([], menuItems)});
```

*Third Try:*

```
  // This line modifies the existing state.
  state = (Object.assign({}, state, {
    menuItems: [
      Object.assign({}, newMenuItem), 
      ...menuItems
    ]
  }));
```

*Fourth Try:*

```
  // This line modifies the existing state.
  state = update(state, {
    menuItems: {$unshift: new Array(newMenuItem)}
  });
```

Comment: Can you check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477055/how-can-i-dispatch-function-in-redux