# How can I dispatch function in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a Cart array in the redux store that contains all the items I added it to cart

like this

```
const initialState = {
  cart: [
    {
      product: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Pizza cheese',
        price: 100,
        image: require('../../assets/food-3.png'),
        description: 'Tempor aute culpa ad voluptate aliquip ad ad laboris.',
      },
      quantity: 3,
    },
    {
      product: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Steak meal',
        price: 200,
        image: require('../../assets/food-2.png'),
        description: 'Tempor aute culpa ad voluptate aliquip ad ad laboris.',
      },
      quantity: 2,
    },
  ],
};
```

and I have an input to add a coupon code, and when I added it should decrease the total price,
so how can I achieve these if I didn't store a total in the store?
and render the total price after adding this coupon!

here is my code snippet

reducer/index.js

```
import {
  ADD_COUPON,
  ADD_TO_CART,
  MINUS_FROM_CART,
  PLUS_FROM_CART,
  REMOVE_ITEM,
} from '../actions/types';

export default cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART: {
      return {
        cart: [
          ...state.cart,
          {
            product: action.productInfo,
            quantity: action.quantity,
          },
        ],
      };
    }
case PLUS_FROM_CART: {
  return {
    ...state,
    cart: state.cart.map(item => {
      if (item.product.id === action.productInfo.product.id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          quantity: action.quantity + 1,
        };
      }
      return item;
    }),
  };
}

case MINUS_FROM_CART: {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    cart: state.cart.map(item => {
      if (item.product.id === action.productInfo.product.id) {
        return Object.assign({}, item, {
          quantity:
            action.quantity <= 1 ? action.quantity : action.quantity - 1,
        });
      }
      return item;
    }),
  });
}

case REMOVE_ITEM: {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    cart: [
      ...state.cart.filter(
        ({product}) => product.id !== action.productInfo.product.id,
      ),
    ],
  });
}

case ADD_COUPON: { // here is
  console.log(state.cart);
  return {
    ...state,
    newTotal:
      state.cart.reduce(
        (total, item) => total + item.quantity * item.product.price,
        0,
      ) - 50,
  };
}

default:
  return state;


}

};
```

cart screen

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
  Dimensions,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import CartIcon from '../components/CartIcon';
import CartItem from '../components/CartItem';
import {
  MinusFromCart,
  plusFromCart,
  removeItem,
} from '../store/actions/actions';

class CartsScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    delivery: 15,
    total: this.props.total,
    coupon: '',
  };

  applayCoupon = () => { // here is
    const {coupon} = this.state;
    if (coupon == 'Free') {
      this.props.addCoupon();
    }
  };
  handleIncreaseQuantity = (product, quantity) => {
    this.props.increaseQuantity(product, quantity);
  };
  handleDecreaseQuantity = (product, quantity) => {
    this.props.decreaseQuantity(product, quantity);
  };
  handleRemoveItem = product => {
    this.props.removeProduct(product);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={{marginBottom: 5}}>
          <View
            style={{
              borderColor: '#d7d7d7',
              margin: 15,
              borderWidth: 1,
              padding: 15,
              borderRadius: 10,
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
            }}>
            <TextInput
              value={this.state.coupon}
              style={{width: '80%'}}
              onChangeText={coupon => this.setState({coupon})}
              placeholder="Write coupon code"
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.applayCoupon()}>
              <Text style={{color: '#f00'}}>Apply</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              paddingVertical: 5,
              marginBottom: 5,
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              paddingHorizontal: 15,
            }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}>Subtotal</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}>{this.props.total.toFixed(2)}$</Text>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              paddingVertical: 5,
              marginBottom: 5,
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              paddingHorizontal: 15,
            }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}>Delivery Fee</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}>{this.state.delivery}$</Text>
          </View>

          <View
            style={{
              borderTopColor: '#ddd',
              borderTopWidth: 1,
              paddingVertical: 10,
              alignSelf: 'center',
            }}>
            <View
              style={{
                paddingVertical: 5,
                marginBottom: 5,
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
                paddingHorizontal: 15,
              }}>
              <Text style={{fontWeight: '700', fontSize: 18}}>Total</Text>
              <Text style={{fontWeight: '700', fontSize: 18}}>
                {this.props.total + this.state.delivery}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <Text
              style={{fontWeight: '700', paddingHorizontal: 15, fontSize: 18}}>
              after: {this.props.newTotal} $
            </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                padding: 15,
                borderRadius: 10,
                width: width - 20,
                backgroundColor: '#f10',
              }}>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 15, color: '#fff'}}>Checkout</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    cartItem: state.cart,
    total: state.cart.reduce(
      (total, item) => total + item.quantity * item.product.price,
      0,
    ),
    newTotal: state.newTotal
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    increaseQuantity: (product, quantity) =>
      dispatch(plusFromCart(product, quantity)),
    decreaseQuantity: (product, quantity) =>
      dispatch(MinusFromCart(product, quantity)),
    removeProduct: product => dispatch(removeItem(product)),

    addCoupon: () => {
      dispatch({type: 'ADD_COUPON'});
    },
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(CartsScreen);
```

Comment: what about creating an action to calc your cart total then add your coupon to total?
anyway you need to store total in store

Comment: I definitely wouldn't recommend maintaining the total separately in state. Two sources of the same info generally doesn't work out well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation would be to not store redundant (derived) information in state. This means you don't need to (nor should you!) store the total in the state. The main reason this is a problem is that it gives your state an opportunity to contradict itself... if your state's `total` key doesn't equal the sum of the item totals, you've got a big problem!

Instead, you can create a function that calculates the total and simply call that when you need it. For example:

```
const calculateTotal = state => {
  let total = state.cart.reduce((total, item) => {
    return total + item.quantity * item.product.price 
  }, 0);
  // Assuming you just have one coupon, you could maintain a boolean in state
  if (state.hasCoupon) {
    total -= 50;
  }
  return total;
}
```

And then, anywhere in your code you need to get the total, you can simple use this function. It's not uncommon to include this sort of function in `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  total: calculateTotal(state);
});
```

If you end up with a lot of derived state, you may see some advantages from using a selector library like [Reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) which can help you build selectors derived from other selectors and implements *memoization* for performance boosts.

Comment: Thanks, Nick, sorry about that but calculateTotal function should be in which file? Reducer or on any screen I want to make a calculation, and yeah I will check out Reselect

Comment: That function can be anywhere. I'd probably just export it from its own file (e.g., calculateTotal.js)

Comment: Hey @Nick, what's do you mean of `It's not uncommon to include this sort of function in mapStateToProps`

Comment: @DevAS theoretically you could call the function from within the component itself, but it’s common to do so in the mapStateToProps function instead

Comment: @NickI just declare a state`  hasCoupon: true` and that's work perfect, Now :D as you see here https://i.imgur.com/4SsC9Ff.png, I have a Text Input and the user should be writing something like "Nick" to take his discount :V , and I just declare hasCoupon as boolean and i can manipulate it  to accept string , but it should when the user click the apply he will just subtract 50$ from total so how can i handle it !

Comment: @OliverD I don't quite understand the new question; can you rephrase it? Thanks!

Comment: well, as you write in `calculateTotal()` function it just calculates the total and applies the coupon if `hasCoupon == true` Automatically when the cart screen renders, I want to control when to invoke this function! if the user has a coupon and clicks the apply button subtract -50 from the total , As in general shopping apps

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like you shouldn't set the `hasCoupon = true` in state until the user clicks the apply coupon button

Comment: yeah,, exactly!

Comment: So, are you still having trouble?

Comment: No, I do it :D I'm new in redux so yeah I write an action" i'm writing name true? Or it's reducer Not action " to change hasCoupon bool if click the button

Comment: Yeah, the correct terminology is that, when you click the button, you dispatch an action to the reducer. The reducer takes the current state and action and returns a new state.

Comment: @Nick I know its not a nice thing to says but I'm really stuck, if you have time can you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58545261/how-to-achieve-the-notification-counter