# How to achieve the notification counter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have a react native app and after Cloud function send any notification to users I save it in a real-time Database,

In the Home screen, I add a bell   when the user clicks it will navigate him to a specific screen contains all notifications saved to a real-time database( firebase ),

So my question is I want to add a counter if the user gets a new notification it will increase and after a click to the bell and navigate to notifications detail screen and get back to Home screen should be a 0 count or just a bell without a counter,
 how can I do it?

My thought is I just add a listener in the home screen and just get the length of notification array after fetching from firebase and if any new notify to come to the length will increase and after navigating to notification screen I reset the notification array to be [ ] or something, 
*But in every single time*, I open the app and go to "Home Screen" I will get the count "length of notifications array after fetched" .. so that's bad

So what you think?

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer would be to store a count of what has been read locally in AsyncStorage and read that when the app starts.

Obviously it's a pretty limited solution on its own, e.g. it will be wrong if the user uses a different device, eventually the number will roll over, what happens when the notifications are purged from the DB.

As Firebase was mentioned, it may be worth having a look at what their [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) or the Beta [Firebase In-App Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging) service provides by means of help to implement something nicer. Also, if not found it already, the [invertase/react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) collection seems to give access to most of Firebase's functionallity.

Comment: I think Firebase did not mention something about this 